# Why does accessing a value held by a 16-bit register result in a Seg Fault, while doing the same operation on a 32-bit register works fine?

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

I am having issues with using 16-bit registers for a university assignment. The code I am trying to run is as follows:

```
myArray db 1,2,3,4; declared in the correct section
;-----------------
mov si, myArray
mov ax, [si] ; segfault here
sub ax, [si+1]
mov [si+3], ax
```

and

```
mov dx, 1234h
push dx
mov dx, 0ABCDh
push dx
mov bp, sp
mov ax, ss:[bp]
```

Both resulting in a segmentation fault. However, when I run the same code using ESI and RBP registers, it assembles without issues.

I am running it on a VM with Ubuntu 22.04.3. I have heard from a friend (not sure how reliable this is) that x86 64-bit might be blocking direct access to some 16-bit registers and that is why I'm having issues. I brought it up with my professor, but they dismissed me stating it was probably an error in my syntax.

I have tried searching for a solution but was unsuccessful. I originally was using WSL and, thinking it was the issue, switched to a VirtualBox VM, but to no avail.

Comment: Running that code as a 64-bit or 32-bit program won't work. Are you supposed to write a 16-bit program? That's what you're doing but it sounds like you're trying to run it as a 32-bit program. IDK which of these you want, but they don't match.

Comment: @harold I want to write a 16 bit program, what do I need to do for the assembler to recognize that?

Comment: Which assembler? BTW you can't run a 16-bit program directly in Ubuntu, you could try DOSBox

Comment: @harold I don't have a preference in assembler, right now I'm using nasm. That's the part that confuses me is the fact that all the registers are 16 bit, but we have to "mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0  
int 0x80 " at the end of the program meaning its in 32 bits.

Comment: OK well, given that "ending" that only makes sense on Linux, you're supposed to write a 32-bit Linux program after all. There's no such thing as a 16-bit Linux program. You can use 16-bit registers in a 32-bit program, but truncating a 32-bit address to 16-bit is not good.

Comment: @harold So using ebx and esi is the correct thing to do in this case? Thank you so much for your help, this prof is really something:))

Comment: For the address of the array at least yes, otherwise do what you want, actually since you have an array of bytes there it may make more sense to use 8-bit registers for the data (or use `movzx`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov eax, 1
> mov ebx, 0
> int 0x80
> ```

From a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77998650/why-does-accessing-a-value-held-by-a-16-bit-register-result-in-a-seg-fault-whil#comment137508088_77998650) it has been established that you are writing a 32-bit program.
It is fine to use 16-bit registers to hold 16-bit values, but not to hold addresses! Your `mov si, myArray` and `mov bp, sp` are loading an incomplete address. You get the full address with `mov esi, myArray` and `mov ebp, esp`.
For performance reasons, you should not only load the 16-bit register but the whole 32-bit register. Use `movzx` (MOVe with Zero Extension) for this.

### Watch out for buffer overflow

Both `mov ax, [si]` and `sub ax, [si+1]` address two byte-sized array elements at once, but `mov [si+3], ax` is also writing to the byte that comes after the array! Which is possibly another variable and that gets corrupted this way. It is not clear what this first snippet is supposed to achieve, but a rewrite would look like:

```
mov   esi, myArray
movzx eax, word [esi]  ; -> AX = 0201h  (EAX = 00000201h)
sub   ax, [esi+1]      ; -> AX = FEFFh  (EAX = 0000FEFFh)
mov   ???
```

### Watch out for redundancies

In `mov ax, ss:[bp]` the mention of BP as the base address already makes the CPU use the SS segment register. It is the default. No need to explicitly add the segment override `ss:` which, depending on the assembler, could consume an extra byte.
It gets even better since you don't need to use EBP at all. You can address the stack via the ESP register.
The equivalent code for your second snippet becomes:

```
push  1234ABCDh
movzx eax, word [esp]  ; -> AX = 0ABCDh  (EAX = 0000ABCDh)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I see what you mean by accessing 2 bytes at a time, is it possible to access an array such that [whaterver_register + 1] is the second element [whaterver_register + 2] is the third etc. Or is that typically how you would work with an array of bytes, using ah and al to get individual elements?

Comment: @Shadows_Puppet I think that what you want is *scaled indexing*. You load the address of the array in a Base register like EBX and the index [0,3] per your example in an Index register like ESI. Then, for an array with **word-sized** elements, you address the first element (ESI=0) with `[EBX + ESI * 2]`, you address the second element (ESI=1) with `[EBX + ESI * 2]`, you address the third element (ESI=2) with `[EBX + ESI * 2]`, ... For an array with **byte-sized** elements you replace `* 2` by `* 1` and for an array with **dword-sized** elements you replace `* 2` by `* 4`.